# Crystal report to rounding

Tags: crystal-reports, rounding, crystal-reports-xi

I have a currency field in my report that displays some values. I then do a summary of these values and it gets rounded off.

For eg., if my summary value is `40.706` it gets rounded to `40.71` which is fine, but when my value is `40.704`, it gets rounded as `40.70` (this is correct according to rounding principles) but I want it to show as `40.71` since it is a currency.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a `0.004` (or `0.005` if you want also that happened for 40.700) to you original value then round it.